# IF VAR batch file not working

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, cmd

Can any one tell me why this is not working. i want it to **`goto`** when i type ether 1 or 2 but it keeps going to `ECHO ERROR` when i type the number can any one help :-).

```
ECHO OFF

ECHO Loading...

SET option=0

SET /P option=Choose a number and press enter. :

ECHO %option%

if "%option" == "1" GOTO one

if "%option" == "2" GOTO two

GOTO EXIT

:one

ECHO hello

GOTO EXIT

:two

ECHO hi

GOTO EXIT






:EXIT
ECHO EXIT
Taskkill /f /im program.bat 2>%USERPROFILE%\temp.txt



ECHO ERROR

pause
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
if "%option" == "1" GOTO one
```

should read:

```
if "%option%" == "1" GOTO one
```

ditto for the second case.

`ERROR` will always be displayed as it will fall through from `EXIT`, if you want a case for `ERROR`;

```
:EXIT
ECHO EXIT
GOTO EOF

ECHO ERROR

:EOF
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if "%option" == "1" GOTO one

if "%option" == "2" GOTO two
```

Where is the closing percent sign here?